# how to convert associative array in to one array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array

I am stuck on this i have multiple associative array and i want to convert in to one:-
Here is the array:-

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Women
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => children
        [1] => smile
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Abstract
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Lion
        [1] => Cheetah
    )
)
```

I want output something like this:-

```
Array
(

[0] => Women
[1] => children
[2] => smile
[3] => Abstract
[4] => Lion
[5] => Cheetah
)
```

Here i have tried so far:-

```
$getKeywords =  DB::table('contributor_images')->select('keywords')->get();
$getKeywords = json_decode(json_encode($getKeywords),true);
    foreach($getKeywords as $keyword){
        $AllKeywords[] = $keyword['keywords'];
    }
    foreach ($AllKeywords as $key => $ExplodeKeywords) {
        $searchkeywords[] = explode(',',$ExplodeKeywords);
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($searchkeywords); die;
```

I am using laravel framework of php. THANKS IN ADVANCE :)

Comment: Try [array_flatten](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-array-flatten)

Comment: hey @JoeBlack thanks

Comment: post answer i will accept it

Comment: Ok, posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel helper function [array_flatten](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-array-flatten) for this:

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        0 => 'Women',
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => 'children',
        1 => 'smile',
    ],
    2 => [
        0 => 'Abstract',
    ],
    3 => [
        0 => 'Lion',
        1 => 'Cheetah',
    ],
];

$result = array_flatten($array);

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'Women' (length=5)
  1 => string 'children' (length=8)
  2 => string 'smile' (length=5)
  3 => string 'Abstract' (length=8)
  4 => string 'Lion' (length=4)
  5 => string 'Cheetah' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($old as $data) {
            foreach ($data as $value) {
                $new[] = $value;
            }
        }
        print_r($new);
    }
```

In first foreach you are getting array inside array and in second foreach you will get the value. Insert these values in new array to get desired result. Use `print_r` to see the result

Comment: too complex see @JoeBlack answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use : **`call_user_func_array`**

```
<?php
$array = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Women',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'children',
    1 => 'smile',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Abstract',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Lion',
    1 => 'Cheetah',
  ),
);

$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);

print_r($result);
?>
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Women
    [1] => children
    [2] => smile
    [3] => Abstract
    [4] => Lion
    [5] => Cheetah
)
```

Check here : https://eval.in/829111

> Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 5.7 the syntax is `Arr::flatten($array)` so that now it looks like

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$array = [
    0 => [
        0 => "Women"
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => 'children',
        1 => 'smile'
    ],
    2 => [
        0 => 'Abstract'
    ],
    3 => [
        0 => 'Lion',
        1 => 'Cheetah'
    ]
];
Arr::flatten($array);
```

Output :

```php
array:6 [
  0 => "Women"
  1 => "children"
  2 => "smile"
  3 => "Abstract"
  4 => "Lion"
  5 => "Cheetah"
]
```

Docs be [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-flatten)